# Place a string onto the command line without execution

Tags: command-line

Suppose I have a variable

```
let g:f_themes="./themes/**"
```

Suppose I want to map this command to a key:

```
:execute "vimgrep /".expand("<cword>")."/g ".g:f_themes." | copen"
```

That works, even though it may complain about not finding `<cword>`. I can deal with that.

But what if I want to instead place that string onto the command line and NOT execute it, which allows me to inspect and edit the command before hitting `<cr>`. I can't use :execute because it will go ahead and execute. And I can't get the value of `g:f_themes` to expand to `./themes/**` if I just type the command without the :execute.

Is there a way to place a string onto the command line so that a simple `<cr>` would go ahead and execute the line?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the evaluations of expressions into the command-line (or a buffer) with the expression register, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>. You can also use this in a mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>gt :vimgrep /<C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR>/g <C-R>=g:f_themes<CR> <bar> copen
```

See `:help quote_=` for more details on the expression register and `:help c_CTRL-R` for specific notes on using it in command-line mode.

**EDIT**: You mention in a comment that you'd like to be able to do this without any mapping being involved. You can use `feedkeys()` for this:

```
:call feedkeys(':vimgrep /' . expand("<cword>") . '/g ' . g:f_themes . ' | copen')
```

This can be run from the command-line, or directly within a function (that has not been invoked by a mapping).

Comment: This is good stuff. I didn't know about feedkeys(). By the way, this technique seems to be a good way to do specific greps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got part of the answer: how to map a key to do this.

First, declare this one-line function (1):

```
exe "function! Temp(cword) \n return ':vimgrep /'.a:cword.'/ '.g:f_themes.' | copen' \n endfunction"
```

Then do this key mapping (2):

```
:nnoremap <expr> <Leader>gt ':'.Temp(expand("<cword>"))
```

It puts this on the command line:

```
:vimgrep /mycword/ ./themes/** | copen
```

Just what I wanted.

A couple of points:
(1): You can't use bars (`|`) to separate lines in a compressed function.
(2): You need `<expr>`. Learn something new every day.
You need to quote the `:`.
You need to use `expand()`.
Or it won't work.
I don't know if `Temp()` could directly refer to `<cword>`.

But now there is another question.
What if one wanted to pump the command line directly from a function. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: 1: I just used :execute to make the function a one-liner. 2: Note that I was using a key map that took the return value of a function and pumped the command line with that. What I was wondering about was the ability to pump the command line directly from within a function, without having any key mapping involved.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I wondering how a :call Whatever() type command could pump the command line, or if it could.